# Create directory using a variable as the name

Tags: java

Maybe its something simple i am over looking, but i need to be able to create sub directories using a list of numbers stored in a txt file. When i use a string literal it creates the directory, but when i switch to using the variable being used for the items in the list it will not. Here is the code block.

```
private static void GetJarDir() throws URISyntaxException {
    CodeSource codeSource = NewJFrame.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    File jarFile = null;
    jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
    jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath().replace("dist", "").replace("build", "");
    mainFolder = jarDir + "Invoices\\";
}
```

this is the method i use to get the directory for the jar file and append the path with the directory i need to create the sub-directories in, i'm sure this works.

```
BufferedImage dest = image.getSubimage(0, 3377, 465, 80);
String newDir = new OCR().recognizeEverything(dest);
File theDir = new File(mainFolder + newDir);
new File(mainFolder + newDir.mkdirs();
```

im using an optical character recognition library to grab an invoice number off of a cropped image. So newDir is the invoice number. Ive printed out the path and it is the correct path, it is just not creating the directory. If i change the variable to the actual invoice number it works, any ideas?

```
new File(mainFolder + "223545").mkdirs();
```

so sitting here playing with it ive narrowed the problem down to the string returned from the OCR. It has to be a string or it wouldnt compile...but when i try to parse the string to an int it throws an exception. and it is in fact an integer

Comment: `new File(mainFolder + "223545".mkdirs();` won't even compile, so it can't possibly have been copied from working code.

Comment: You might print everything and make sure that all of the path separators are where they should be.

Comment: sorry, i typed that in by hand because it was so short and not actually a piece of code im trying to use, i left out the second parenthesis, edited and fixed.

Comment: OK, my second comment still stands. Is it possible that in one case you have "foo" and in another case you have "/foo", so that when you append to "bar" you are getting "barfoo" instead of the expected "bar/foo"?

Comment: i have printed everything, the file path that returns when i use "123456" is the exact same as when i use a variable in its place, ive edited the post, the problem is with the string returned from the ocr, but i dont understand how or why. if i define the string as "123456" and then use the variable in its place the file path is the same except it actually works.

Comment: So you printed `mainFolder + newDir` and it looks ok? Maybe split up the `new File(mainFolder + newDir)` from `theDir.mkdirs();` to help with the debugging. I find that if I try to do too many things in one line, it makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: I apologize because i knew when i wrote this i was over-complicating things and i hate wasting peoples time on here, but i found it, there was a space hiding at the end of the string returned from the OCR so i needed to trim it before using it.